# django-admin error with decoding

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I have a problem with " **django-admin startproject mysite .** " command. When I try to execute it, Cygwin returns me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/django-admin",
>   line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('Django==1.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'django-admin')()   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 359, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 294, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 345, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py",
>   line 34, in handle
>       super(Command, self).handle('project', project_name, target, **options)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/templates.py",
>   line 164, in handle
>       if new_path.endswith(extensions) or filename in extra_files: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position
>   22: ordinal not in range(128)

- I am running this command in Cygwin 6.3
- Python version: 3.5.2
- Django version: 1.10.2

Maybe it's important: I had a serious issue with django-admin.py file (django installer didn't install it) but I found a following content of that file and maybe it's incorrect?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

I was reading about that problem in Python 2.x but not in 3.x and I can't find the answer. Please, somebody help me with that.

Comment: It is without dot. `django-admin startproject mysite . ` > `django-admin startproject mysite`

Comment: You are also using the Python 2 installed Django. The Django you use lives in `py2.7.egg`. Just create an env and start your project from there. Eg: `virtualenv -p python3 env`, `env/bin/pip install django` and `env/bin/startproject mystie`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that Django is trying to start in Python verison 2.7. Try changing your default Python interpreter to `python3` or `python3.5`.

Or at least you can try to change the first line of your `django-admin.py` to be: `#!/usr/bin/env python3.5`

Comment: I checked my PATH environment variable and I have there " C:\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Python35\;C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.10.2-py3.5.egg\django\bin " and I think it seems correctly. Is that a way to set a default Python interpreter or not? Second advice didn't working :/

Comment: @RafałM., but the exception you provided tells, that it's actually a "Django-1.10.2-py**2.7**.egg/..."

Answer (score 0):

It was a lack of openssh package in Cygwin. Make sure that you have it installed (I haven't)